# Error starting Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

Can anyone help troubleshoot Datastax Opscenter installation? Its a new install on clean Ubuntu 14 server. Using apt-get to install, no issues, /var/log/opscenter is empty, but getting the following after tring to start the service, and it doesn't run:

root@unigmadevdse3:/var# service opscenterd start
root@unigmadevdse3:/var# service opscenterd status
 * could not access pidfile for Cassandra cluster manager opscenterd            root@unigmadevdse3:/var#

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of OpsCenter that you are trying to install? Could you check the ownership/permissions of /var/run/opscenter? Also, can you please check disk space on /var? Try using su to switch to the opscenter user and try `$ touch /var/run/opscenter/opscenter.pid`. Be sure to remove it after.